# J-1 visa holder applying for German research visa

Tags: germany, employment, j-visa

I am currently in the US as a J-1 visa holder, and I am applying for a researcher visa in Germany soon.

I have noticed that in the visa application form there is a field for "residence permit number" and the corresponding expiration date, but I am unsure as to what to write in that field, since the visa itself and the DS-2019 have different number and different expiration dates.

Could anyone inform me which of them is expected in the form?

Comment: The standard advice is "ask the German consulate to whch you're applying." Have you tried asking them?

Answer (score -1):

I would put the visa number and expiration date.  The DS-2019 is neither a visa nor a residence permit.

Comment: Given that I had no intention of leaving the US this year, my visa is currently expired. But my J-1 program is, of course, still valid until the expiration of my DS-2019. And to be fair, the visa is also not a residence permit, it's more like an entry permit...

Comment: @PerpendicularBox indeed, the thing that reflects your authorization to stay in the US is your I-94 form.  You'll have to include that somewhere.  Maybe the "residence permit" entry is the place for that.

Comment: Visa is not a residence permit, it's only relevant to entry decision. One may consider I-94, or check if the field is at all mandatory (maybe they want an A# if the applicant has it?) Checking with the consulate IMHO is the way to go.